# Классы наследники не видят динамически созданной переменной?

Tags: наследование, php

Во время исполнения php скрипта происходит динамическое создание полей класса class1 (перегрузка). Но вот беда, классы наследники класса class1 не видят динамически созданной переменной, как исправить положение?

```
class class1{
    function registerVar($name,$value){
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
class class2 extends class1{
    index(){
        $this->name = $value;
    }
}
class class3 extends class1{
    //Здесь не видно $this->name
}
```

Comment: класс class3 наследует class3, сам себя что ли?

Comment: опечатался, он также наследует class1

Comment: попробуй через parent::$value, или делай это все через конструктор

Comment: "может быть" нужно указать поле $name в классе class1

Comment: А зачем Вам потребовалось динамическое создание полей? Мне кажется, это неверный путь решения некой другой Вашей проблемы.

Comment: созданием динамических полей мне понадобилось для создания удобного апи) и я пошел немножко другим путем)

Answer (score 2):

Перегружайте getter и setter и достигнете искомого результата.

```
<?
class  class1{
    private static $properties=Array();
    function __set($name, $value){
        class1::$properties[$name]=$value;
    }
    function __get($name){
        return class1::$properties[$name];
    }
};
class class2 extends class1{
    public $garbage='class2';
};
class class3 extends class1{
    public $garbage='class3'; // поля определенные в классе будут разными и наследников.
};
$x=new class2;
$y=new class3;
$x->test=5; // у $y тоже теперь есть поле test, динамической связывание так сказать
echo ($y->test).' '.($x->garbage).' '.($y->garbage); // 5 class2 class3
$x->garbage='new';
echo $y->garbage; // class3
?>
```

---

**Вариант 2**.
Динамические поля создаются специальной функцией.

```
<?
class  class1{
    private static $properties=Array();
    public function regVar($name, $value){
        class1::$properties[$name]=$value;
    }
    function __set($name, $value){
        if (array_key_exists($name, class1::$properties)){
            class1::$properties[$name]=$value;
        } else {
            $this->$name=$value;
        }
    }
    function __get($name){
        if (array_key_exists($name, class1::$properties)){
            return class1::$properties[$name];
        } else {
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }
};
class class2 extends class1{
    public $garbage='class2';
};
class class3 extends class1{
    public $garbage='class3'; // поля определенные в классе будут разными и наследников.
};
$x=new class2;
$y=new class3;
$x->test=5;
$y->test=6;
$x->regVar('qwerty', 'uiop');
echo ($x->test).' '.($y->test).' '.($x->garbage).' '.($y->garbage).' '.($x->qwerty).' '.($y->qwerty); // 5 6 class2 class3 uiop uiop
$x->garbage='new';
echo $y->garbage; // class3
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Но этот вариант мнене походит, статическия поля не наследуются. А мне по-мимо всего прочего нужно что бы создоваемые поля были и у наследников

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду `private static $properties`? Наследникам и не нужно его наследовать. Они получают к нему доступ через `__get` и `__set`.

Comment: Всё верно, только static делать не нужно. Иначе для всех экземпляров класса будут одни и теже данные.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что автор хочет создать динамически поле в экземпляре class2 и чтобы оно появилось в экземпляре class3

Comment: Да, что то я не дочитал..